# How to check the configuration keys available for a QEMU cpu?

Tags: qemu

According to the QEMU user manual, I should be able to use the `,help` to check the further info about an option.

From the sample command below, it seems `pauth-impdef` can be used to configure the `-cpu max`.

`-cpu max,pauth-impdef=on`

So I try to check what other configurations are available for `-cpu max` like below:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu max,help
```

But what I got is:

> qemu-system-aarch64: Expected key=value format, found help.

This basically says nothing useful. So what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

For Arm, the CPU feature options are documented [on this page](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/arm/cpu-features.html). The page also describes how to probe for supported feature names if you need to automate that.

I agree that it would be nice if 'help' worked on the -cpu option, so I've filed [a wishlist bug](https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/1480) about that.

Comment: Thanks! I have upvoted your wish list bug.

Answer (score 0):

We can use QMP (QEmu Monitor Protocol) commands to check a lot of things, including some available configuration entries.

For how to run QMP interactively, check:
https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/QMP